# How to click this button by using puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to click the button using puppeteer but have no idea how to locate the button.

Here's the HTML and I want to click the [エクスポート] button.
(Sorry but I cannot show you this website link because I would need to tell you login info)

```html
<div class="resultsHeader-side">
 <button class="css-15qe8gh-button css-ykx4dy-buttonFocus css-1emi1z8-buttonWidth css-15kjecu-buttonHeight css-q66qvq-buttonCursor" type="button">
   <div class="css-k3dwai-innerContainer css-173b0b-innerContainer-md css-gkwbws-innerContainerColor css-sthj4j-innerContainerBorderRadius css-ft3bob-innerContainerHeight">
   <svg class="css-1g69qe9-iconDirection" height="14px" width="14px" viewBox="0 0 14 14">
   <path class="css-idjrra-path" d="M9 0l4 4v9c0 .552-.448 1-1 1h-10c-.552 0-1-.448-1-1v-12c0-.552.448-1 1-1h7zm-1 8v-4h-2v4h-2l3 3 3-3h-2z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>エクスポート
   </div>
 </button>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `page.click(selector[, options])` [documentation](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v14.1.1&show=api-pageclickselector-options).
For you it could be something like:

```js
await page.click('div.resultsHeader-side > button')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a great chrome extension that generates puppeteer scripts. You can use it to click your button and then trim what you don't need.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/headless-recorder/djeegiggegleadkkbgopoonhjimgehda?hl=en